# Can we determine a number of objects in a category?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness, compactification

Maybe my question is too idealistic, but I try it:

Is there any way to look at a category and be able to tell whether this category has zero, one, countable, infinite or any particular number of objects? If not generally, is it possible in particular cases of categories? And what about determining if the category has/hasnt initial or terminal object?

**The example that motivated me for this question**: If we have a topological space and take all its compactifications, which form a category - are we able to determine (using category theory tools or whatever else), how many objects are there in the category?

Comment: In a sense, such a question is a wrong question to ask. In category theory, we hardly care about what a particular object looks like. We care about the relationship between an object and the rest of the objects in the category. We care about universal properties. We are hardly ever interested in asking "how many objects are isomorphic to this particular object".

Comment: It is a classic theorem that any Grothendieck toposes contain a natural number object. In the category of sets, it is the set of natural numbers. Also, the real number object is defined. I answered the part of the question ''is it possible in particular cases of categories?'' and you delete it. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to look at a category and be able to tell whether this category has zero, one, countable, infinite or any particular number of objects?

No, you have to analyze each category separately. There is no and can't be a general method (as in algorithm) for solving that.

> If we have a topological space and take all its compactifications, which form a category - are we able to determine (using category theory tools or whatever else), how many objects are there in the category?

If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is any set with a bijection $f:X\to Y$ then $Y$ can be given a topological space structure via $U\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. In that way $f$ becomes a homeomorphism. And therefore if $K$ is some compactification of some space $X$ then any set $Y$ (equinumerous to $K$) can be turned into a space homeomorphic to $K$, and thus $Y$ can be turned into compactification of $X$. Homeomorphic, but distinct from $K$. Therefore the category of compactifications is at least as big as the category of all sets of a fixed cardinality, which is a proper class.

Even up to homeomorphism compactifications are at least as big as the category of sets. If $K$ is a compactification of some $X$ and $Y$ is any set, then the disjoint union $K\sqcup Y$ together with $\{U |\ U\text{ open in }K\}\cup\{K\sqcup Y\}$ topology is a compact space such that $X$ embeds into it as a dense subset.

The thing becomes interesting if we consider Tychonoff spaces only (the construction above is never Tychonoff). In that situation it can be shown that if $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $K$ its Tychonoff compactification, then $|K|\leq 2^{2^{|X|}}$. And therefore, unlike other situations, Tychonoff compactifications form a set, but only up to homeomorphism. Still, the precise cardinality heavily depends on $X$ and I don't think such classification exists.

**Edit:** I will show the $|K|\leq 2^{2^{|X|}}$ inequality when $X$ is Tychonoff. Of course if $X$ is finite then it has to be compact discrete and we cannot embed it into any other compact Tychonoff space (as a dense subset), thus $|K|=|X|$.

Now assume $X$ is infinite and consider $\beta X$, the [Stone–Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $X$. It is known that every compactification of $X$ is an image (even quotient) of $\beta X$. This follows directly from the universal property of $\beta X$: given an embedding $f:X\to K$ into compact $K$ with dense image, we have the induced map $\beta f:\beta X\to K$ whose image is at least $f(X)$. But since $\overline{f(X)}=K$ then $\beta f(\beta X)=\overline{\beta f(\beta X)}=K$ and thus $\beta f$ is onto. Therefore the cardinality of any compactification is at most $|\beta X|$.

Now how is $\beta X$ constructed? One way is to construct it as a certain subset of $[0,1]^C$ where $C=\{f:X\to[0,1]\ |\ f\text{ is continuous}\}$ with the open-closed topology (see the wiki on Stone–Čech). And therefore any compactification is of cardinality at most $\frak{c}^{\frak{c}^{|X|}}$ where $\frak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$ denotes the cardinality of reals. Thus the cardinality is at most $2^{\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0\cdot |X|}}$. But since $X$ is infinite then the above simplifies to $2^{2^{|X|}}$.

Note that $2^{2^{|X|}}$ boundary cannot be improved. It is well known that the Stone–Čech compactification of naturals is of such cardinality. Which of course doesn't answer the question: how many non-homeomorphic compactifications are there for a given $X$?

Comment: That is a fantastic reply! However, I dont understand the part about how any equinumerous set Y can be turned intu a space homeomorphic to compactification of X?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova assume that $K$ is a compactification of $X$. Now let $Y$ be any set and $f:K\to Y$ a bijection. As I wrote in my answer: transfer topology from $K$ to $Y$ so that $f$ becomes a homeomorphism. Now if $i:X\to K$ is an embedding with $i(X)$ dense in $K$, then $f\circ i:X\to Y$ is an embedding with $f\circ i(X)$ dense in $Y$. Thus $Y$ is a compactification of $X$.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova or maybe my original claim was not clear enough? $Y$ is supposed to be equinumerous to some compactification of $X$, not to $X$.

Comment: Could you provide a source for the proof that $| K | \leq 2^{2^{| X |}}$ for Tychonoff spaces? Also, I could have specified before, that I consider Hausdorff compactifications only, which (if I am correct) assumes that all spaces must be Tychonoff. Nice answer though, thank you!

Comment: @TerezaTizkova yes, for compact spaces Hausdorff and Tychonoff are the same. And so if a space has Hausdorff compactification then it has to be Tychonoff itself (because it is hererditary property). These are the same in this case.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I've updated the answer with cardinalities calculation.